# How can I call a method from another class?

Tags: java, android, chronometer

I can't figure out how to call the start(); method from a class I made It is in the same package and it is called Chronometer here is me class

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import com.example.chrono.Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.os.SystemClock;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class tests extends Activity{
    Button start;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Chronometer test = new Chronometer(this);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                com.example.chrono.Chronometer.start();         } 
        }); 
    }

}
```

i get the error on `com.example.chrono.Chronometer.start();`

the error is **Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method start() from the type Chronometer**

Comment: replace this line com.example.chrono.Chronometer.start();  with test.class(); and try

Comment: Show your `start()` function!! Maybe you try to call `non-static` function as a `static` function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Call non static method's from other class as using object of `Chronometer` class:

```
Chronometer test = new Chronometer(this);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        //    com.example.chrono.Chronometer.start();
            test.start(); 
         } 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call this method like this `test.start();`

Answer (score 2):

A `static` method (without getting into the details) is a method that is called directly from the Class, such as `MyClass.staticMethod();`. You are attempting to call an `instance` method, which needs to be called from an *instance* of MyClass. In this case, your method start is not static, but is an instance method, and should be called using:

```
test.start();//since, test is an instance of your class.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class tests extends Activity implements OnChronometerTickListener {
}
```

put your class like this ...........

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `Composition` to access the **method** of **another class**.

**-** Create an instance of Chronometer in test Class and access the start() method.

**Eg:**

```
public class tests extends Activity{
Button start;
Chronometer crono = new Chronometer();   // Instance of Chronometer

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Chronometer test = new Chronometer(this);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            crono.start();        
        } 
    }); 
  }

}
```

**Few important things:**

**-** Use Capital letter for 1st alphabet in Class name, eg.. Test

**-** Make sure about the proper `access modifiers` to be used on the Class and its methods, in order to make it visible to other classes